# Convert 32-bit program to 16-bit program

Tags: linux, assembly, gnu-assembler

Assembler throws error for my 16 bit code
movzbw  (%ax), %ax
Error: `(%ax)' is not a valid base/index expression

But the below instruction is valid on 32 bit code generation.
movzbl  (%eax), %eax

Environment:
Processor: Intel(x86)
Assembler: "GNU AS"
Operating System: "Linux"
Purpose: While writing a very simple bootloader which prints "Hello, World" to the screen, I am trying to pass a string to a function and then traverse byte by byte and then print it.

What is the equivalent instruction that I can use to avoid error in writing 16 bit real mode code?

More information:
Below is the C code that I am trying to simulate in "16 bit GNU AS" assembler

```
void _prints(char*);


int main(void)
{
   char* mess = "hello";
   _prints(mess);
   return 0;
}

void _prints(char* str)
{
   while(*str)
   {
      ++str;
   }
}
```

Note:While trying to generate the assembly  file using command "gcc -S test.c",
I see that in _prints function the instruction "movzbl  (%eax), %eax".
I want to simulate a 16-bit real mode code using the same assembler, but it throws error while using "movzbw  (%ax), %ax"

Please help

Comment: There have been other duplicates. Please, read the documentation on addressing of memory operands.

Answer (score 2):

In real mode, `(%ax)` (`[ax]`) is not a valid indirect addressing method. You have to use the `%bp` register. I recommend you pick up the Intel (or AMD) processor manuals and read Volume 2 (for Intel) from front to back, as I did.

If you are just removing the `e` to simulate real mode, there is no need. Your program will not compile to a 16-bit executable. It will still be a 32 or 64 bit executable with `gcc`. The only way to generate 16-but executables is with OpenWatcom. Even then, there is *no* need to write 16-bit programs. They are slow and the switching between real and protected mode (change executing thread) is expensive on the processor.

As you mentioned this is for a bootloader, you can't write a bootloader like this. You have to write the assembly by hand. No exceptions that I'm aware of.

Comment: In 16-bit mode, real or protected.

Comment: .code16

.section .data
   message: .ascii "Welcome to c0mrade"

.section .text
.globl _main
   _main:
   pushw message
   call  _putchar
   jmp   _hang

   _putchar:
      pushw %bp
      movw  %sp, %bp
   _putcharl:
      movw  4(%bp), %ax
      movzbw (%ax), %ax
      testb %al, %al
      je    _putchare
      movb  $0x0e,  %ah
      movb  $0x00,  %bh
      movb  $0x07,  %bl
      int   $0x10
      addw  $1, 4(%bp)

      jmp   _putcharl
   _putchare:
      movw %bp, %sp
      popw %bp
   ret
   _hang:
      jmp _hang

.section .boot_signature
   .word 0xaa55

.end

Comment: sorry for the code indentation.....but the code does not work as expected "Traversing byte by byte and print the character"

Comment: You can't write a bootloader this way. A compile outputs object files that are more than just code. Those are then linked into an _executable_ with sections. A bootloader is _raw_ assembly and has _no_ sections.

Comment: but i was able to generate a binary out of this program and was able to run through bochs x86 emulator.

Comment: You may e able to make a binary, but it still is an executable, _not_ raw code. If you want to write a bootloader, (pardon my French) RTFM.

Comment: Probably you will have to look into my source files, linker files and makefile for generation of binary. But I am sure that I am generating a flat binary file.

Comment: Ok, but GCC doesn't output 16-bit code. So you may be generating a flat binary, but it is 32-bit code. Incidentally, the 32-bit code may interpret to functionally equivilent 16-bit code, but it isn't 16-bit code.

Comment: Oh sorry...I am not using gcc but instead i am using "GNU AS" assembler

Comment: Then what seems to be the problem? If you want to code your bootloader in C, you can't.

Comment: I knew it already but I am trying to understand how to write a function which traverses through the string and print it byte by byte to the screen in 16-bit real mode using stacks in GNU AS assembler in AT&T syntax.

Comment: You need to learn interrupts.

Comment: @ColeJohnson There is a 16 bit protected mode since the 286.

Comment: @demonkoryu Are you referencing the dreaded "Unreal mode"?

Comment: @ColeJohnson No, that's 16 bit real mode with 32 bit flat descriptors in shadow segment registers. For PM16, I'll refer you to here: www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/protected-mode

Comment: @demonkoryu Oh that. That's not protected mode _per se_, but it is. It's actually called [Virtual 8086 Mode](http://wiki.osdev.org/Virtual_8086_Mode)

Comment: @ColeJohnson No, V86 mode is a virtualization of (16 bit) Real Mode from within PM that's only available since 386 (as is PM32). PM16 exists since 286.

Comment: @demonkoryu Oh! The 286. I don't really consider the 80286 a protected mode processor as it is still 16-bit.

Comment: @ColeJohnson The defining feature of Protected Mode is a memory protection mechanism, which Real Mode lacks. The size (16/32bit) or layout (segmented/flat) of the memory space doesn't change the principle.

Comment: @demonkoryu No, I agree with you that it is. I'm just saying that if you ask an assembly programmer about Protected Mode, they'll think of the 32-bit mode before the 16-bit mode. I have yet to see an operating system that runs in 16-bit protected mode.

Comment: OS/2 1.x and Windows 3.x used PM16, but I agree, it's not like anyone on the world would be targeting PM16 today.